# Matlab vs C++ find first element of Matrix that is equal to something

Tags: c++, matlab, matrix

Why this algorithm doesn't work in Matlab as it works in C++?

```
 int a[3][4] = {  
   {0, 1, 1, 1} ,   /*  initializers for row indexed by 0 */
   {1, 0, 0, 0} ,   /*  initializers for row indexed by 1 */
   {0, 0, 0, 1}   /*  initializers for row indexed by 2 */
};

 int x,y;   
        for(int i=1;i<3;i++)
            for(int j=1;j<4;j++)
            {
                if (a[i][j]==1) // if element is equal to 1, get his position and stop.
                {
                    x=i-1;
                    y=j-1;
                   break; 
                }
            }
        cout<<x<<" "<<y; // 1 2
```

If i'm trying to do something like this in Matlab the output is not the same ( not even close). In fact it doesn't work at all.

Matlab code:

```
for i=1:m
    for j=1:n
        if(a(i,j)==1)
            k=i-1;
            l=j-1;
            break;
        end
    end
end
```

How should i do it?

Comment: 1. break only breaks the inner for-loop, thus it's not the first appearance, but the first appearance int the last row. 2. C++ indexing start with 0, Matlab indexing with 1, thus `x=i-1;` and `y=j-1;` is not equal to `k=i-1;` and `l=j-1;`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not that the `break` is ignored, but it only breaks out of the inner loop and just continues in the outer loop. I'm afraid there's no "break twice" instruction or something similar. One solution would be to have a flag to also break in the outer loop:

```
int x, y;
bool stop = false;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        if (a[i][j] == 1) // if element is equal to 1, get his position and stop.
        {
            x = i - 1;
            y = j - 1;
            stop = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (stop)
        break;
}
```

It's one of those very rare cases where you can put a `goto` to make it less of a kludge:

```
int x, y;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        if (a[i][j] == 1) // if element is equal to 1, get his position and stop.
        {
            x = i - 1;
            y = j - 1;
            goto finishNestedLoop; // used as a "break twice"
        }
    }
}
finishNestedLoop:;
```

Other solutions include putting the nested loop into its own function and using `return` instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
std::tuple<int, int> getXY() {
    int a[3][4] = {
       {0, 1, 1, 1} ,   /*  initializers for row indexed by 0 */
       {1, 0, 0, 0} ,   /*  initializers for row indexed by 1 */
       {0, 0, 0, 1}   /*  initializers for row indexed by 2 */
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            if (a[i][j] == 1) // if element is equal to 1, get his position and stop.
                return std::tuple<int, int>{i-1, j-1};
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    auto[x, y] = getXY();
    std::cout << x << " " << y;
}
```

---

On a side note, are you sure about the `i - 1`? To go from 0 to 1-indexed, you'd need `i + 1`.

Comment: I realy dislike the use of `std::tuple` here. It is so heavy and overused...

Comment: @user1810087 yeah, people user it inappropriately a lot. But I think in this case it's the least awful way of returning two values. What would you suggest?

Comment: @user1810087 to my understanding returning multiple values from a function is one of the main features tuple was pushed for

Comment: @JHBonarius actually that's how it was in the question until OP (incorrectly) changed it

Comment: True, if you want to return multiple values in a [quick fassion](https://arne-mertz.de/2017/03/smelly-pair-tuple/), tuple most likely fit's best. `std::pair` could be another unaesthetic option. I probably should correct my statement to: I really dislike the use of `std::tuple` **anywhere**. Just feeling uncomfortable around tuple... Maybe having a class or struct representing the index coordinates, but this would also be an overkill for such a small example... I don't know, good anser +1 :D

Comment: @Blaze `if (stop)break;` should be inserted right after the inner loop, not at the beginning to break the entire loop immediately.

Answer (score 0):

- It is a matter of proper use of `break` in MATLAB. From https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/break.html, you will see that there is a statement:

> In nested loops, break exits only from the loop in which it occurs.
>   Control passes to the statement that follows the end of that loop.

Thus, with MATLAB, you could use `break` in the following way

```
stopFlag = 0
for i=1:m
    for j=1:n
        if a(i,j)==1
            k=i-1;
            l=j-1;
            stopFlag = 1;
            break;
        end
    end
    if stopFlag
      break;
    end
end
```

- If you want to do it in a more efficient way in MATLAB, you can try the following code:

```
[r,c] = find(a'==1)
k = r(1)-1;
l = c(1)-1;
```